# Why fetching(API) gives me undefined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I created an API using Flask, and it is working perfectly when using it in Postman, giving me JSON.
Anyways, when I try to fetch it in javascript, it is giving me undefined:

```js
api = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/';

const getData = () => {
  fetch(api)
    .then(response => {
      response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
};
getData();
```

As I said, when I try to log the data, it prints

```js
undefined
```

Comment: Your first `then` cause is not returning the value either remove the braces or add `return` in front of `response.json()`

Answer (score 7):

You need to return your json data(`return response.json();`), fixed snippet:

```js
api = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/';

const getData = () => {
  fetch(api)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
};
getData();
```

Comment: or you can use `then(response => response.json())`

Answer (score 1):

You get undefined because you dont return anything. Every function returns undefined if you dont `return` something.

```
api = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/';

const getData = () => {


fetch(api)
  .then(response =>{

     return response.json();

    })
```

`.json()` is asynchronous too so you will need an `.then()` block after ur function call.

```
getData().then( res => {
   console.log(res);
});
```